# Laravel - Capturar y tratar una excepción

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-8, laravel-7

Tengo esta función en mi controlador de laravel (expresamente creo la excepción de 1/0), que quiero ver como tratar esta excepción.

Esta función tiene un código más largo y complejo pero como ejemplo nos sirve, mi idea es capturar  cuando salte cualquier tipo de excepción y mediante una entidad que tengo **ErrorCapturados**, guardar esos datos en base de datos para posteriormente revisar que ha pasado.

Tal como tengo este código me salta una excepción con la plantilla de laravel y me gustaria que aparte de hacer el "create" a ErrorCapturados me mostrase el "dd" que tengo al final del código, pero no me llega hasta allí.

```
public static function obtenerCliente(Request $request)
{

    try {

        $codigo_cliente = 'test';
        $a = 1/0;

    }
    catch (Exception $exception) {

        $dataObj = [
            'action' => 'ClientesController@list',
        ];

        ErrorCapturados::create([
            'user_email' => $codigo_cliente,
            'error' => $exception->getMessage()
        ]);

        dd('error cliente');
    }

    return $result;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pudes probar agregarle

`catch (\Exception $exception) {....}`

Una solución que utilizó para trabajar los errores es con el api de [rollbat] (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://rollbar.com/&ved=2ahUKEwjYu5qZh_TyAhVJQTABHcYWD4AQFnoECCsQAg&usg=AOvVaw2flOcvAlGV0OB3dbwlSPCN)
Además creo un handleException para que capture todos mis errores sin importar donde y enviarlo al api antes mencionado, por emal, o como quieras tratarlo, pero mi principal recomendación es el api te ayudará a tratar los errores como equipo de trabajo y en tiempo real,

$códigocliente Está Fuera del contexto del catch por lo que tendrás un nuevo error y no podrás capturar partiendo del ejemplo